# How to connect to a WiFi using CMD only?

Tags: networking, windows-10, security, cmd.exe

How to connect to a new WiFi by entering a password using CMD?

For my school project I have decided to make a WiFi_manager program using cmd.

I know to display all WiFi networks (in cmd):

```
netsh wlan show networks
```

Now let's say I want to connect to a WiFi network that I never connected to before. And that WiFi is not added any profiles also.

But I know the password for the WiFi.

**What will be the command line for that.**

Given the information on WiFi network below:

```
SSID 3 : Ismail
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP

and password is "Thanks_bro".
```

I search this question already in google but none of them say the right way and most of them are related to hacking and connecting a WiFi without password etc. So I posted this question to the BEST programmers out here to answer!

If not possible, can we do using C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately if you want to connect to a wireless network from command prompt that requires a passcode it won't happen.

First of all to connect to a wireless network with a password you need to setup a profile or you need to have an already set up profile you can check that profile by using

```
Netsh wlan show profiles
```

To see your profile you need to be connected to that wifi at least once .

The alternative way is to have a generated created xml profile and use the following command to connect to it :

```
netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME interface="WIRELESS NETWORK CONNECTION"
```

More info could be found [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx)  in this article

Comment: Check this ,it is helpful for you [How can i connect to ad-hoc network using CMD? ](https://superuser.com/questions/1275646/how-can-i-connect-to-ad-hoc-network-using-cmd/1275748#1275748)

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, you can easily connect to a password-protected wireless network using only the command prompt.

First, create an XML file with your Wi-Fi connection details. Use this as a template, replacing `{SSID}` (appears twice) and `{PASSWORD}` with your own:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>{SSID}</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>{SSID}</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>{PASSWORD}</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
    <MacRandomization xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
        <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
    </MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

Next, create your batch file (again, replace `{SSID}` with your own):

```
@echo off
netsh wlan add profile filename="{whatever you named the file}.xml"
netsh wlan connect name="{SSID}"
echo.
pause
```

Inspired by this Q&A here (and my own need to do this today):
https://superuser.com/a/1275748/243707

---

*But why stop there?*
Combine the whole thing into a single script, and clean up any XML clutter afterwards.

```
@echo off

set "SSID=enter your network name here"
set "HEXSTR=enter your password here"
set "XML_OUTPUT_PATH=%TEMP%\%SSID%-wireless-profile-generated.xml"

echo ^<?xml version="1.0"?^>^<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"^>^<name^>%SSID%^</name^>^<SSIDConfig^>^<SSID^>^<name^>%SSID%^</name^>^</SSID^>^</SSIDConfig^>^<connectionType^>ESS^</connectionType^>^<connectionMode^>auto^</connectionMode^>^<MSM^>^<security^>^<authEncryption^>^<authentication^>WPA2PSK^</authentication^>^<encryption^>AES^</encryption^>^<useOneX^>false^</useOneX^>^</authEncryption^>^<sharedKey^>^<keyType^>passPhrase^</keyType^>^<protected^>false^</protected^>^<keyMaterial^>%HEXSTR%^</keyMaterial^>^</sharedKey^>^</security^>^</MSM^>^<MacRandomization xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3"^>^<enableRandomization^>false^</enableRandomization^>^</MacRandomization^>^</WLANProfile^> >%XML_OUTPUT_PATH%

netsh wlan add profile filename="%XML_OUTPUT_PATH%"
netsh wlan connect name="%SSID%"

del "%XML_OUTPUT_PATH%"
echo.
pause
```

Comment: This is the extended version of what the older answer suggests in the second part.