# How can i connect to ad-hoc network using CMD?

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, cmd.exe, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to connect my computer (PC1) to an existing [ad hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) using cmd commands.This ad hoc was created by second computer(PC2),i spend hours to find results but i did find an answers.See this photo to understand me.

[image]
I tried these commands :

```
Netsh wlan export profile  folder=”c:\profiles” name="Profile 1" interface="Wireless Network Connection"


Netsh wlan add profile filename=C:\Users\WirelessUser\Documents\profile1.xml interface="Wireless Network Connection"
```

But i can't keep my need.

I need some steps to creating a profile for ad hoc (this ad hoc was created by other machine ),or should i use other methods by using cmd  ?

Comment: What happens if you try to connect it manually?

Comment: Every thing is well , but i need commands for my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- create an XML file and copy/past these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
<name>{SSID}</name>
<SSIDConfig>
    <SSID>
        <name>{SSID}</name>
    </SSID>
</SSIDConfig>
<connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
<connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
<MSM>
    <security>
        <authEncryption>
            <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
            <encryption>AES</encryption>
            <useOneX>false</useOneX>
        </authEncryption>
        <sharedKey>
            <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
            <protected>false</protected>
            <keyMaterial>{password}</keyMaterial>
        </sharedKey>
    </security>
</MSM>
<MacRandomization 
xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
    <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
</MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

2- replace the keywords {SSID} (occurs two times) and {password} with the desired values

3- call that file in cmd (navigate first to its location):

> netsh wlan add profile filename="file_name.xml"

4- then execute this command:

> netsh wlan connect name="SSID"

NB: the same SSID used in XML file!

and boom, it will connect!

Note:

1- Pay attention to spelling the SSID (uppercase and lowercase letters)

2- SSID = "hotspot name"

Comment: At moment every thing is well ,but i have this error: `Unable to connect to the network specified by the profile`.

Comment: Be sure you did this: **navigate first to its location**

Comment: Nice. This gets my vote. This can of course be combined with other commands to connect to a password-protected wi-fi network for the first time using only the command prompt (non-interactive): https://superuser.com/q/1157209/243707