# Unable to connect to the network specified by the profile {profile_name } because it is not available

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, command-line

Yesterday i had the problem with the method of communication between two computers using CMD.Today i found the method [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1275646/how-can-i-connect-to-ad-hoc-network-using-cmd?noredirect=1&lq=1) but only step remaind when i use this command

```
netsh wlan connect ssid="peer" name="peer"
```

I found this error :

```
Unable to connect to the network specified by the profile {profile_name } because it is not available
```

This is my xml file content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
<name>peer</name>
<SSIDConfig>
    <SSID>
        <name>peer</name>
    </SSID>
</SSIDConfig>
<connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
<connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
<MSM>
    <security>
        <authEncryption>
            <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
            <encryption>AES</encryption>
            <useOneX>false</useOneX>
        </authEncryption>
        <sharedKey>
            <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
            <protected>false</protected>
            <keyMaterial>123456789</keyMaterial>
        </sharedKey>
    </security>
</MSM>
<MacRandomization 
xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
    <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
</MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

and this a screenshot of profiles :[image]
Where is the problem ?

Comment: Sorry ,i forgot them ,i will edit my question.

Comment: @Ramhound , when i use GUI every thing i well , but i need commands for java project.

Comment: @Ramhound I just  changed  ad-hoc name to peer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70010/discussion-between-xlint-xms-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 3):

I think i see where the problem is, you are passing the path of the xml file in the filename attribute (look at cmd screenshot).

Instead, you have to navigate to its location with 'cd' command.

Comment: This is the answer.  The author failed to do what the answer to his other answer indicated to do

Comment: But my file path is : 'D:\profile.xml` and when i change it i have this error :`The specified file can not be found`

Comment: anyway bruh, i'm applying the same solution i provided and its working as a charm here! any ample information will be helpful to fix this

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, it surely gets connected without any problem :

```
netsh wlan connect name="YOUR-SSID"
```

Or

```
netsh wlan connect name="YOUR-SSID" interface="wi-fi"
```

Answer (score 0):

### BATCH SCRIPT

@echo off

REM Connect to a WiFi network

ECHO.
SET /p SSID="WIFI SSID : "

ECHO.

ECHO Connecting to the SSID %SSID% ...

ECHO.

### netsh wlan connect name="%SSID%" interface="wi-fi"